# Merge / match two variables with one group of variables from another dataframe

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, match, plyr

I have two data.frames `df.1` and `df.2` that I would merge or otherwise select data from to create a new data.frame.  `df.1` contains information about each individual (`ID`), sampling event (`Event`), `Site` and sample number (`Sample`). The tricky part for me is that `Site` and the corresponding `Sample` for each `ID`-`Event` pairing is different. For example, F3-3 has `Site` "plum" for `Sample` "1" and M6-3 has `Site` "pear" for `Sample` "1".

[image: data.frame df.1]

`df.2` has `Sample1` and `Sample2` which corresponds to the `Sample` information in `df.1` by way of the `ID`-`Event` pairing.

[image: data.frame df.2]

I'd like to match/merge the information between these two data.frames. Essentially, get the "word" from `Site` in `df.1` that matches the `Sample` number. An example (`df.3`) is below.

[image: data.frame df.3]

Each `ID`-`Event` pairing will only have one `Site` and corresponding `Sample` (e.g. "Apple" will correspond to "1" not to "1" and "4"). I know I could use `merge` if I was only matching, for example, `Sample1` or `Sample2` I am not sure how to do this with both to populate `Site1` and `Site2` with the correctly matched word.

```
df.1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("F1", 
"F3", "M6"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), Event = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Site = structure(c(1L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 
2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
1L), .Label = c("Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Guava", "Kiwi", 
"Mango", "Orange", "Peach", "Pear", "Plum"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Sex", "Event", "Site", "Sample"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-37L))
 #
 df.2 <- structure(list(Sample1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L), Sample2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
 3L, 4L, 5L), V1 = c(0.12, 0.497, 0.715, 0, 0.001, 0, 0.829, 0, 
 0, 0.001, 0, 0.829), V2 = c(0.107, 0.273, 0.595, 0, 0.004, 0, 
 0.547, 0.001, 0.001, 0.107, 0.273, 0.595), ID = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F1", 
 "M6"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
  Event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Sample1", 
  "Sample2", "V1", "V2", "ID", "Sex", "Event"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -12L))
 #
 df.3 <- structure(list(Sample1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L), Sample2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
 3L, 4L, 5L), V1 = c(0.12, 0.497, 0.715, 0, 0.001, 0, 0.829, 0, 
 0, 0.001, 0, 0.829), V2 = c(0.107, 0.273, 0.595, 0, 0.004, 0, 
 0.547, 0.001, 0.001, 0.107, 0.273, 0.595), Site1 = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Apple", 
 "Banana"), class = "factor"), Site2 = structure(c(2L, 8L, 6L, 
 7L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Banana", "Grape", 
 "Guava", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Orange", "Peach", "Pear", "Plum"), class = "factor"), 
 ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F1", "M6"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", 
 "M"), class = "factor"), Event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Sample1", "Sample2", 
 "V1", "V2", "Site1", "Site2", "ID", "Sex", "Event"), class = "data.frame", row.names =   c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `merge`s should do it:

```
first <- merge(df.2, unique(df.1[,3:5]), by.x=c("Sample1","Event"), by.y=c("Sample","Event"), all.x=TRUE)
second <- merge(first, unique(df.1[,3:5]),by.x=c("Sample2","Event"), by.y=c("Sample","Event"), all.x=TRUE)

print(second)
   Sample2 Event Sample1    V1    V2 ID Sex Site.x Site.y
1       10     1       1 0.000 0.001 F1   F  Apple   Kiwi
2        2     1       1 0.120 0.107 F1   F  Apple  Grape
3        3     1       1 0.497 0.273 F1   F  Apple   Pear
4        3     3       2 0.001 0.107 M6   M Banana  Mango
5        4     1       1 0.715 0.595 F1   F  Apple Orange
6        4     3       2 0.000 0.273 M6   M Banana  Guava
7        5     1       1 0.000 0.000 F1   F  Apple  Peach
8        5     3       2 0.829 0.595 M6   M Banana   Kiwi
9        6     1       1 0.001 0.004 F1   F  Apple   Plum
10       7     1       1 0.000 0.000 F1   F  Apple Banana
11       8     1       1 0.829 0.547 F1   F  Apple  Mango
12       9     1       1 0.000 0.001 F1   F  Apple  Guava
```